# Infinite running of game

Tags: java

I am trying to make a small 2D java game by following this [YouTube Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idb6-Zfdq2Q&index=5&list=PLah6faXAgguMnTBs3JnEJY0shAc18XYQZ).

I am not following it 100% but sort of along those lines. When I try to run my program, it opens infinitely and does not stop opening. I have turned it into a thread(??) and added starts and stops but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
public class game implements Runnable {

private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

public game(){

}

private void init(){
    new frame();
}

private void update(){

}

private void render(){
    frame frame = new frame();
    bs = frame.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null){
        frame.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
}

public void run() {
    init();
    while(running){
        update();
        render();
    }
    stop();
}

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It runs off a Launcher class like so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    game game = new game();
    game.start();
}
```

I can ive the full code if need be. I have tried asking the creator and looking at his source code but everything seems to be identical (apart from the display deviations I have made to alter my game from his.)

TL:DR Game opens infinite frames and eventually crashes.

Comment: You may want to add your constructor and possibly (static) initializer blocks of code (or indicate that you have none, of course).

Comment: Is `running` a static variable? Where is `running` being stored?

Comment: You should probably extract the thread handling code from the `Game` class (note the upper case letter which should be used for class names as to prevent confusion) - `thread.join()` would be called inside the thread you're joining on. That's not your problem though, please show us what `init()`, `update()` and `render()` are doing.

Comment: @user3437460 why shouldn't it compile? Us humans could be confused but to the compiler it should all be clear.

Comment: @Thomas Interesting, I always deem that as very bad coding habit hence I didn't even try it before. Yea, that can compile (just tried). But nonetheless, bad coding style.

Comment: It compiles but as I mentioned before, it runes an infinite number of times and does not stop opening new frames.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to my render() method as to what is causing the problem(commented it out and it worked fine without it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make getCanvas() method static and it worked. Simple.